# How do I deal with type casting by property assignment when transforming with typescript/jsdoc?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

```js
type FromType = {
  // [...]
  value: string;
}

type ToType = Omit<FromType, 'value'> & {
  value: number;
}
```

then

```js
/**
 * @param {FromType[]} records
 * @returns {ToType[]} records
 */
function transform(records){
  return records.map((record) => {
    record.value = parseFloat(record.value);
    
    return record;
  });
}
```

Complains because `record.value` is expected to be a string. A workaround is to use `Object.assign`

```js
/**
 * @param {FromType[]} records
 * @returns {ToType[]} records
 */
function transform(records){
  return records.map((record) => {
    return Object.assign(record, {
      value: parseFloat(record.value),
    });
  });
}
```

How can I handle type casting on assignment?

Assume:

- It's safe to mutate.
- I don't want to define an incorrect input property having `string | number`.
- I don't want to make new objects for performance reasons i.e. `{ ...item, value: 0 }`;

Comment: Shouldn't those types be `FromType[]` and `ToType[]`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My bad, fixing it

Comment: Also, the type of `ToType["value"]` is `never`, because it's `string & number`. If you want to redefine the type of `value` when defining `ToType`, you need to omit `value` before doing the intersection: `type ToType = Omit<FromType, "value"> & {/*...*/};`.

Comment: *"I don't want to make new objects for performance reasons.*" It would be an **extraordinary** situation for that to be performance concern. Do you have an **actual** performance problem, or is this premature optimization? :-)

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/mxk01N) is the likely way you'd do it with TypeScript type annotations, ugly as those type assertions are. (I don't know the equivalent using JSDoc annotations.) TypeScript's not especially well-suited to mutation scenarios where a type is completely changed (not just narrowed).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've fixed the ToType as well, but it's not really the focus of the question I'm specifically asking about handling the type changing on assignment. Initially I wrote "real world performance reasons" to avoid a tangental conversation, but shortened it. Just take what I asked at face value, it doesn't involve some minor UI update in react.

Comment: Also, doing it this way would modify the FromType object to be a ToType which is risky to say the least. Anything that uses any of those FromType object will be getting a number instead of a string.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon I'm aware and the first bullet point in my question has already covered that. There's very good reasons why mutations are used here. I'm not asking about when it's safe to mutate.

Comment: @KitSunde - Issues with immutability go a **lot** further than "minor UI update(s) in React," but yes, leave that to the side. Well, hopefully my [example of how you'd do it with TypeScript type annotations](https://tsplay.dev/mxk01N) helps (did you not see that?). I'd assume you can translate that to JSDoc type annotations.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah if you post it I'll accept it until someone has a better idea. I suspected that may be the only way to do it (overriding the type before transforming). I'm aware of all issues around performance and immutability, dealing with performance, scalability and system stability is a large part of my career, it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @KitSunde Oh my bad dude. I completely misread the question.

Comment: @KitSunde - Very belatedly I wonder: Why copy the array? :-) So I've added a note to my answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With apologies, I don't know how to annotation this with JSDoc, but with TypeScript's own type annotations in order to perform that mutation you'd briefly lie to TypeScript to trick it into allowing it:

```typescript
type FromType = {
    // [...]
    value: string;
};

type ToType = Omit<FromType, "value"> & {
    value: number;
};

type X = ToType["value"];

/**
 * @param   records The record to transform.
 * @returns Transformed records.
 */
function transform(records: FromType[]): ToType[] {
    return records.map((record) => {
        const result = record as any as ToType;     // A brief lie...
        result.value = parseFloat(record.value);    // ...which is now true
        return result;
    });
}
```

[Live example on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgewLYBVzQLxQN4CgoFQD0RUA2gHRUC6+hAbgIYA2ArhAFxQDOwcAlgDsA5gG5cAX3G5QkKCgRo5WAPJJ+wADzxkSiABooAIiZsIRgHxQAZDjoFT7LoNZIARhDjipuGeigAGlBYCnpkJizsRtTSRABUcfhxUAACYIxwjEiEcBAAxghwACbc8gAW0LkFxVDACLWZgtwAZoVIFEmpucCscE3yjS1tEEVQVYUlHVBxRLjNrIJ5wPwIgg2MTa1wSAAU48XcXDqo6GTUAJRcoafUdoRjED19D9WTSIxgO3v5E+fBVnh7vcCk1gA9uKxmGCsPtRoxShsQFB4fJFOhRECSFAAIJQNwCCDNKDMfgQKhTIEEXIQqEURyYKDpODcCAwZgIRjAb6vOmRCDnDGELHkgDuZX4eTKUH4pUECBFDXY9iB3V6a2pkOA4nuEgFkiAA)

If you could avoid mutation, I would strongly encourage it (it would then just be `return records.map((value, ...rest) => ({...rest, value: parseFloat(value)}));`), but if you can't avoid it, you can't avoid it. :-)

Since you're mutating the objects, unless you have a very unusual use case, there's no reason to create a new array, and not doing so may also help with your performance issue:

```typescript
/**
 * @param   records The record to transform.
 * @returns The **same** array, objects are mutated in place.
 */
function transform(records: FromType[]): ToType[] {
    for (let n = records.length - 1 ; n >= 0; --n) {
        const record = records[n];
        const result = record as any as ToType;     // A brief lie...
        result.value = parseFloat(record.value);    // ...which is now true
    }
    return records as any as ToType[];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgewLYBVzQLxQN4CgoFQD0RUA2gHRUC6+hAbgIYA2ArhAFxQDOwcAlgDsA5gG5cAX3G5QkKCgRo5WAPJJ+wADzxkSiABooAIiZsIRgHxQAZDjoFT7LoNZIARhDjipuGeigAGlBYCnpkJizsRtTSRABUcfhxUAACYIxwjEiEcBAAxghwACbc8gAW0LkFxVDACLWZgtwAZoVIFEmpucCscE3l0AncWRAJUBmZIB1QcUS4zayCecD8CIINjE2tcEgAFFWFJVw6qOhk1ACUXKFn1HaEUNtQu8wQwFDrWAfF3BSvIsAylAALRQACMUFEHygFiwAAYocDgYILvcHoQCk13t8isEoDjuGRBDF7OjMbx8RBuKxmO8vvlDuNSpsQEz5Ip0FCHiQoABBKBuAQQZpQZj8CBUabogi5am0iiOTBQdJwbgQGDMBCMYD7BnFBWRCAXLkEHmSgDuZX4eSB-FKggQ5oa7FJElJ3V66wJbJZbJukHO3lwQA)

Even if you do need to create a new array, given that this function is mutating in place, it probably makes sense to have that be something the caller does (perhaps via `slice`, which is very fast).